# Postgresql date now() not working much data insertion

Tags: postgresql

I created a column on my table.

```
create_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
```

I want to add automatically insertion time to `create_date` column.

if I insert one data to databsae,  it works. But I am using a third party program to insert that inserts so much data at one time. For example (10000) insertion. So this time all of my `create_date` values are being null. But if third party data is less than about 200, `create_date` is filled.

What is the reason of this issue?

Comment: Apparently that third party program explicitly supplies a NULL value for that column

Comment: I updated post. if third party data is less than about 200, `create_date` is filled.

Comment: Without the code doing the inserts this is impossible to answer why this happens. If you want a workaround you can create a trigger that overwrites NULL values with the current timestamp.